Concern with Gregory's argument for particle-like mutual gravitation of two spheres
I am reading Chapter 3 of Gregory's Classical Mechanics wherein he gives, among other things, a fairly careful treatment of graviation by different extended mass distributions. Eventually, he comes to the classical example of a symmetric sphere (defined as a system with a continuous mass distribution $\rho(r)$ which depends only on the radial coordinate from an origin which is at the center of the symmetric sphere) and gives the standard theorem due to Newton:

Theorem 3.1 The gravitational force exerted by a symmetric sphere of mass $M$ on a particle external to itself is exactly the same as if the sphere were replaced by a particle of mass $M$ located at the centre.

My concern is with his claim after the proof:

Since any element of mass is attracted by a symmetric sphere as if the sphere were a particle, it follows that the force that a symmetric sphere exerts on any other mass distribution can be calculated by replacing the sphere by a particle of equal mass located at its centre. In particular then, the force that two symmetric spheres exert upon each other is the same as if each sphere were replaced by its equivalent particle. Thus, as far as the forces of gravitational attraction are concerned, symmetric spheres behave exactly as if they were particles.

I am not buying that this follows immediately from Theorem 3.1. Let's take two symmetric spheres, 1 and 2, which have masses $M_1$ and $M_2$ and do not overlap at all. Denoting the force of $j$ on $i$ by $F_{ij}$, all we can claim from Theorem 3.1 is that
$$F_{12} = \int_{V_1}\frac{GM_2 \cos \alpha}{R^2}\rho_1 \, dV$$
and
$$F_{21} = \int_{V_2}\frac{GM_1 \cos \alpha}{R^2}\rho_2 \, dV$$
where the subscripts on the integrals denote integration over the respective volumes, where $\alpha$ is the angle from the piece of mass $\rho_idV$ to the center of the attracting mass, and where $R$ denotes the distance from the volume element $dV_i$ to the center of the gravitating sphere which we are treating as a particle per Theorem 3.1. In particular, I do not agree with Gregory that we immediately have $F_{12} = \frac{GM_1M_2}{L^2}$ where $L$ is the distance between the centers of the two symmetric spheres.
Obviously it's a true claim, but given that Gregory has been so careful in his exposition I wanted to confirm that there's a further step of proof needed: namely simplifying the integrals above just a touch further in order to show, indeed, that $F_{12} = \frac{GM_1M_2}{L^2}$ with $L$ the distance between the centers of the two spheres.

More on Newton's shell theorem.

There's a missing step, which is simple but slightly tricky. You need to use Newton's third law.
Suppose we want to calculate the force of the first sphere on the second sphere. By theorem 3.1, the gravitational field of the first sphere at any point in the second sphere stays the same if we replace the first sphere with a point mass. But by Newton's third law, we know that this is equal in magnitude to the force of the second sphere on that point mass. This depends on the gravitational field of the second sphere at the point mass, so we can use theorem 3.1 a second time to replace the second sphere with a point mass as well. This gives the conclusion. No integration is required.

I am not sure I follow so, if it's OK, I'll write out the steps in somewhat painstaking detail to confirm. I'll use $P_i$ to denote the particles corresponding to the spheres $S_i$. We are interested in calculating $F_{S_1S_2}$, say. Theorem 3.1, as you say, lets us replace sphere 2 with a particle of mass $M_2$ at the center of sphere 2 for the purposes of calculating $F_{S_1S_2}$: $F_{S_1S_2} = F_{S_1P_2}$. Now I think you're saying that we invoke Newton's Third Law to get being sloppy with the vectorial nature of things here) that $F_{S_1P_2} = F_{P_2S_1}$.

But then a further application of Theorem 3.1 yields $F_{P_2S_1} = F_{P_2P_1}$. We then get the desired result by returning this to our original equation.

@EE18 Yes, that's exactly it!
